# How to hide the first letter of the span?

Tags: jquery, html

Here in my HTML page data in span tags given below:-

```
<span>1 this is a span one.</span>
<span>2 this is a span two.</span>
<span>3 this is a span three.</span>
```

Output

```
1 this is a span one.
2 this is a span two.
3 this is a span three.
```

How I will hide the `1,2,3` values without *REMOVING them and alert them using JQuery when each span is clicked.

Output I want

```
this is a span one.
this is a span two.
this is a span three.
```

and alert them on click means if first is clicked then it alert 1 if second then two if third then 3. Thank you

Comment: You could wrap an element with `display: none;` around it.

Comment: Is the value you want to hide always an incremental number? If so you can remove them and just display the index of the element on click

Comment: @barskey can you write something which help me

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah its an increment number when i remove it then how i will alert it?? can you help me?

Comment: @vikaskumar Take a look at roy's answer, that should work.

Comment: @vikaskumar sure, I added an answer for you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah it works thankyou sir

Answer (score 4):

Take a look to this:

```js
$('span').each(function(){
    var firstLetter = $(this).text().substr(0,1);
    $(this).html('<i style="display:none">'+$(this).text().substr(0)+'</i>'+$(this).text().substr(1));
    $(this).on('click', function(){
        alert(firstLetter)
    })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>1 this is a span one.</span>
<span>2 this is a span two.</span>
<span>3 this is a span three.</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0h1cjxu4/6/

Comment: I am saying when i click on the each span then it alert the values

Comment: Yes Sir, done, maybe next time try to be more politic when someone is helping you.

Comment: there is a Query If there is two digit number then it will only hide the first letter i Want to hide only count like if there are 1 lakh span then it will only hide the 1 lakh number can it is possible??

Comment: Yes, compare if the first word is a number and is done.

Comment: i just comffused can you please tell me.@Roy

Comment: Yes, of course, you have a string with text and numbers and you dont know where  the numbers end, so, try getting the first 3 spaces of the string and validate that is a number (100-999), if not, get the first 2 and validate number (10-99), if not, get the first space (0-9) and check if number. You can validate number with regex or jQuery.isNumeric()

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you can wrap the leading number in the HTML with another `span` which you can find when the outer `span` is clicked:

```js
$('span').html(function(i, h) {
  return h.replace(/^(\d+)/, '<span class="hidden">$1</span>');
}).click(function() {
  var number = $(this).find('.hidden').text();
  console.log(number);
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>1 this is a span one.</span>
<span>2 this is a span two.</span>
<span>3 this is a span three.</span>
```

Alternatively, if the numbers are always incremental then you can simply remove them and display the index of the clicked `span`:

```js
$('span').html(function(i, h) {
  return h.replace(/^\d+/, '');
}).click(function() {
  var index = $(this).index() + 1;
  console.log(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>1 this is a span one.</span>
  <span>2 this is a span two.</span>
  <span>3 this is a span three.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that you don't *need* jQuery.

You can do the following using native JavaScript:

- use a `.forEach()` to loop through your `span` elements,
- use a new `span` element with a new `class="hidden"` to hide the first letter,

See snippet:

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
spans.forEach(function(span, index) {
  var firstLetter = span.textContent.substr(0, 1);
  span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML.replace(firstLetter, '<span class="hidden">' + firstLetter + '</span>');
  span.onclick = function() {
    console.log("You clicked span", firstLetter);
  }
});

console.log('Our "span one" HTML:\n', spans[0].innerHTML);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span>1 this is span one.</span>
<span>2 this is span two.</span>
<span>3 this is span three.</span>
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

Then, you must want to use numbers > 9:

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
spans.forEach(function(span, index) {
  span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML.replace(/^(\d+)/, '<span class="hidden">$1</span>');
  span.onclick = function() {
    console.log("You clicked span", span.querySelector('.hidden').textContent);
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span>10 this is a span ten.</span>
<span>42 this is a span forty-two.</span>
<span>144 this is a span one-hundred-forty-four.</span>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by below HTML and CSS. Need to change the span to div or p tag.

```css
div.abc::first-letter {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">ABCB1</div>
<div class="abc">ABCB2</div>
<div class="abc">ABCB3</div>
```

Comment: There's a couple of issues with this. Firstly, the OP is using inline `span` elements where this won't work. It will also have issues if the leading number is 10 or greater.

Answer (score -1):

Find all `span` nodes using

`const spans = container.find('span');`

then iterate each span and add new string value into `result` variable.

```js
const container = $('#container');
const spans = container.find('span');
let result = '';

spans.each(function( index ) {
 const text = $(this).text();
 const displayText = text.substring(1);
   result += displayText + "\n";
});

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <span>1 this is a span one.</span>
  <span>2 this is a span two.</span>
  <span>3 this is a span three.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: this neither hides the first character, nor provides the requested alerting functionality...

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
  <script>
       $("span").each(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/[1234567890]/, ""));
});
    </script>
```

Comment: this effectively removes them, which the question specifically asks not to do

Comment: @MandarDhadve I dont want to remove them

Comment: @MandarDhadve this still just removes the number.